# Populating Multiple Identical Models with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a page where I have text boxes to fill in information for 10 players (Name, Character, Kills, Deaths, Assists), and once I click 'Save' on that page, I want to populate a player Model for each player, and then somehow access those players in the Postback action where I will be inserting that data into my database. How can I do this?

I know I could name the text boxes:

- Player1, Character1, Kills1...
- Player2, Character2, Kills2...
- etc...

and then have all of those fields in a PlayerList model, and then it would auto populate the PlayerList model with all of the player information, but that seems like its not a very good way of doing it. Let me know if you have any insight.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can name a textbox name="Player[1]"  and have a

```
Dim Player As List(Of String)
```

I'm pretty sure you can also have name="Player[1].Name"